# how save changes for edit page in adminpanel?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

please help solve the problem. i install devise and activeadmin gems. i add field 'superadmin' to User model. after i create user instance via console.

schema.rb:

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
  .......
  ...........
  ....
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.boolean  "superadmin"
end
```

after i add into app/admin/user.rb follow:

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  permit_params :email, :password, :password_confirmation

  index do
    selectable_column
    .....
    column :created_at
    column :superadmin
    actions
  end

  form do |f|
    f.inputs "Admin Details" do
      f.input :superadmin
      f.input :email
      f.input :password
      f.input :password_confirmation
    end
    f.actions
  end
end
```

i try fill field 'superadmin' via admin panel. but after press button 'save' database changes is not saved. i need to fix this.

please tell me which file use. or show me the specific documentation page

ps:
also i generate user_controller.rb and try follow:

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  private
    def person_params
      params.require(:person).permit(:email, :superadmin, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include `superadmin` into list of permitted parameters:

```
permit_params :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :superadmin
```

Rails doesnot allow you to update models from [parameters](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html) without explicit permission.

Comment: i add into user_controller permitted params, but problem still exists. please see on question, i edited and add code to PS-block

Comment: you need to add them to `permit_params` list in `ActiveAdmin.register User` block